# Function in one library calls overridden delete[] in another library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I wrote a test program using googletest. The program links two libraries, `gtestd.lib` and `util.lib`, both of them are built using VS2010 with /MDd

In `util.lib`, the C++ operators new and delete are overridden.

```
inline  void * _cdecl operator new[]( size_t cb )
{
    Assert(cb <= UINT_MAX);
    return MemAlloc((DWORD)cb);
}

inline void __cdecl operator delete[]( void * pv )
{
    MemFree(pv);
}
```

Now the strange thing happens in file `gtest-filepath.cc` inside `gtestd.lib`

```
void FilePath::Normalize() {
  .....
  const char* src = pathname_.c_str();
  char* const dest = new char[pathname_.length() + 1];

  .....
  delete[] dest;
}
```

"new[]" calls into "msvcr100d.dll!operator new[]", but "delete[]" calls into "mytestapp.exe!operator delete[]" which is defined in util.lib

I would expect both `new[]` and `delete[]` will call VS runtime library because that is what `gtestd.lib` linking to. But no matter what, I do not understand why `new[]` calls into VS runtime library but `delete[]` calls into the overridden one.

Answer (score 4):

Your program has undefined behavior, because you are violating the rule found in 7.1.2:

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is *odr-used* and shall have exactly the same deﬁnition in every case (3.2).

Remove the `inline` keyword from these definitions.

You also are not following the guidance in 18.6.1, which says that user code may replace array `::operator new[]()`, but when doing so, should provide all of the following:

```
void* operator new[](std::size_t size);
void operator delete[](void* ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept;
```

You have failed to provide the two-parameter `::operator delete[]` overload, used when a constructor throws, and you do not have the correct `noexcept` annotation on your replacement `::operator delete[]` versions.

Comment: void operator delete[](void* ptr, std::size_t size) noexcept; Do you actually mean void operator delete[]( void* ptr, const std::nothrow_t& tag );

Comment: @TJA no I mean the one I said, which I copied straight from a Draft of the Standard